# How can you make the id in the URL be random?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I am looking for a way to create a randomized id that will link to a lobby that will be shown when the shown method is called in rails. As of right now, the url would look like this: http://localhost:3000/lobby/2. I'm looking to replace that 2 with a randomly generated id so you could send that link to friends if you want them to join your lobby. Any ideas?

Comment: I have idea how to go about this. I am very knew to rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should share a bit more information as Gavin said. Knowing what you have already tried can help us give you more/better information on how to proceed.

I hope this sends you the right direction. For generating random IDs you can use **SecureRandom**:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

I'd recommend you add another column to the `lobbies` table, and make it unique:

```
add_column :lobbies, :secure_token, :string, null: false
add_index :lobbies, :secure_token, unique: true
```

Now, in your `Lobby` model, whenever it is created, you can generate a unique token. For simplicity, you can do something along these lines:

```
class Lobby < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_unique_secure_token

  # Rest of the model's code

  private


  def generate_unique_secure_token
    begin
      self.secure_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while self.class.exists?(secure_token: secure_token)
  end
end
```

This will generate a `secure_token` every time a `Lobby` is created. Now in the controller you can use the `secure_token` instead of the `id` to find your `Lobby`. For example:

```
class LobbiesController < ApplicationController 
  def show
    @lobby = Lobby.find_by(secure_token: params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Heads up, `find_by_x` is considered an antipattern.  The preferred solution is `find_by(secure_token: <criteria>)`

Comment: `SecureRandom::uuid` is perfect for this sort of thing. Just be sure that your system has sufficient entropy!

Comment: OP: this answer is a great jumping off point!  You may notice that when you use `Model.find()`, it throws an error (exception) if the record isn't found.  However, `Model.find_by()` doesn't throw an exception!  You can make it throw an exception by using `Model.find_by!()` (notice the bang at the end)

Comment: You're correct, Kieran. Feel free to edit with your suggestions.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a correction, just more information to the OP :)

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Just one more question. Will this change the URL that displays the lobby?

Comment: Not by default.  You can override the `to_param` method for `Lobby`.  I'd check the docs for more info :)

Comment: @AlexCorreiaSantos Could you explain why you add null: false in the migration? That seems to throw up some errors for me.

Comment: @ChrisMartinez It's saying it can't be empty.  If some records were added with empty `secure_token` fields, there'd be no way to access them.  If the errors your getting happen during CRUD actions, it's probably because you're trying to save a record without a `secure_token`

Comment: @ChrisMartinez the reason has been correctly explained by Kieran. It's just a safety-net. You can drop that "null: false" and have the validation only in the model. The error you're getting is likely to be caused by creating a column with `null: false` in a table that already has elements. So you would have to first create the column with `null: true`, iterate over all `Lobbies` and generate their token. After that, you should be able to add the `null: false` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the whole answer since it's great to learn these things, but if you have any questions feel free to ask me!

This is where you should start: [URLSafe Base 64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64)

[Here's a Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations) that's soft of similar to what you want, see if you can expand from there!  If you're new to Rails, be sure to check out Railscasts.  All the pro episodes are available for free on youtube!

Comment: Thanks! I prefer learning it myself, I just didn't know where to start

Comment: I just updated the post.  See what you can do!  If you have any questions, feel free to start up a chat through StackOverflow